# Can't get layout to be in Map Package (.mpkx) in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, layouts, map-package

I'm using ArcGIS Pro version 2.7 and I'm trying to export a Map Package (.mpkx) that includes both my map and my layout. I've tried using the 'Map' option in the Package tool bar and tried the geoprocessing tool 'Package Map'. In neither case does the resulting .mpkx contain my layout. I don't see many options for these tools, so I am not sure what I am missing.

Back in ArcMap 10.7 I was able to export a Map Package (.mpk) and it contained both the data view and the layout. That is why I am expecting ArcGIS Pro to include the layout in the package.

Comment: Project package perhaps https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/project-package.htm#GUID-E2FBD109-5C2E-4E60-8D6F-B8EA79092F91

Comment: .pagx file is required https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/layout-files.htm